# How to delete on a line in a list with Realm

Tags: swiftui, realm, updates

I have a List structure that removes a line with `ondelete`, but while returning the result, the line is deleted but shows an error.

**I think the problem is that the result is not updated correctly.**

What code should I add to update the list?

```
List{
        ForEach(datosRealm.aquaris, id: \.self) { item in
            Text(item.nombre)
        }.onDelete { (indexSet) in
            let aqua = datosRealm.aquaris[indexSet.first!]
            let realm = try! Realm()
            try! realm.write{
                realm.delete(aqua)
            }
        }
    }


import SwiftUI
import RealmSwift
 
final class DadesRealm: ObservableObject {
    @Published var aquaris: [Aquaris]
    private var cargaToken: NotificationToken?
    
    
    init() {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        aquaris = Array(realm.objects(Aquaris.self))
        recargarDatos()
    }
    
    private func recargarDatos() {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        let personas = realm.objects(Aquaris.self)
        cargaToken = personas.observe { _ in
            
            self.aquaris = Array(personas)
        }
    }
    
    deinit {
        cargaToken?.invalidate()
    }
}


class Aquaris: Object {
    @objc dynamic var nombre = ""
    @objc dynamic var litros = ""
    @objc dynamic var tipoAcuario = ""
    @objc dynamic var data : Date = Date()
    
    @objc dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "id"
    }
    
    let mascota = List<Controls>()
}
```

**Error**:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
> NSException
> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Object has been deleted or invalidated.' terminating with uncaught
> exception of type NSException

Comment: Suppose that you tell the compiler to list an array with n number of items.  At the same time, you tell the compiler to delete one of them.  You now have n-1 items.  So the app crashes.

Comment: Not enough info here. It would help if you share your View properties as your realm object definitions (whatever datosRealm and datosRealm.aquaris are)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is taking a live updating Realm results object and casting it to an array, making those objects non-live updating (static)

In other words realm Results objects always reflect the current state of that data; if an object is deleted from Realm, the realm results object will also have that object removed. Likewise if an object is added then the results object will reflect that addition. (noting this is for objects that fit however the results objects was crafted; filtered, sorted etc)

So here's the issue

```
final class DadesRealm: ObservableObject {
    @Published var aquaris: [Aquaris]
    private var cargaToken: NotificationToken?
    
    
    init() {
        let realm = try! Realm()
        aquaris = Array(realm.objects(Aquaris.self))  <- PROBLEM IS HERE
```

So you need to do one of two things

1 - Make aquaris a realm results object

```
@Published var aquaris: Results<Aquaris>? = nil
```

then

```
aquaris = realm.objects(Aquaris.self)
```

or

2 - If you must use that as an array, when the object is deleted from Realm, you also need to delete it from the array to keep them 'in sync'

I advise using suggestion 1 as it will make things easier in the long run.

Comment: @MiquelMolina What kind of sync are you referring to. Sync'ing to the MongoDB Realm server or something else?